# Will running mysqldump on one Percona XtraDB cluster node affect performance on the others?

Tags: mysql, database-backup, percona, percona-xtradb-cluster, mysqldump

I have a Percona XtraDB cluster with 3 nodes. Only one of these nodes is connected to by the application that uses the database.

I would like to perform 'hot backups' simply using `mysqldump` on one of the nodes that doesn't serve the application by running:-

```
mysqldump --opt --skip-lock-tables --skip-add-locks \
--single-transaction --routines > dump.sql
```

Will this affect the performance of the node serving the application? Or would I be ok running this every 2 or 3 hours on one of the other nodes?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Percona XtraBackup (already shipped and used by Percona XtraDB Cluster), that is a hot backup tool (if you are using InnoDB tables only, which you should since you are on PXC), instead of mysqldump. You can use incremental backups if you use Percona XtraBackup. Something like:

- Full backup once a day
- Incremental backups hourly

It will be less strain on the server. You can find more on this in the online documentation:

https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.4/how-tos.html#recipes-for-xtrabackup

There are also some caveats to be aware of when using mysqldump --single-transaction: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction